# I contributed to an HSA in 2014 that was supposed to be for the previous year, but wasn't

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa, mistakes

When I contributed to my HSA in 2014, it was supposed to be for the year 2013.  This wasn't done. Can I correct this?

Thanks,

Comment: It's my understanding that HSA contributions are credited in whichever year they are actually made.  You can't retroactively contribute to the prior year like an IRA or other tax advantaged savings.

Comment: HSA contributions for the previous tax year can be made until the filing deadline of the current year, according to Pub 696. It's not clear though if that is also the deadline for designating to which tax year contributions belong, or whether you can, years later, amend your returns and redesignate a March 1 contribution as for the previous tax year.